# Convex combinations of states yielding a pure state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, density-operator

[Wikipedia states that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix#Formulation)

> Geometrically, when the state is not expressible as a convex
>   combination of other states, it is a pure state.[9] The family of
>   mixed states is a convex set and a state is pure if it is an extremal
>   point of that set.

At the same time, it defines [convex combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_combination) as

> In convex geometry, a convex combination is a linear combination of
>   points (which can be vectors, scalars, or more generally points in an
>   affine space) where all coefficients are non-negative and sum to 1.

I might be very picky, or mistaken, but I'm led to believe that if $|\psi_i\rangle$ are pure states spanning whichever Hilbert space we are dealing with, then (say) $|\psi_1\rangle$ is a pure state and also a convex combination 
$$ |\psi_1\rangle\langle\psi_1|=\sum_ia_i|\psi_i\rangle\langle\psi_i|, $$
with $a_1=1$ and $a_i=0$ if $i\neq1$.

Am I misinterpreting something? Is Wikipedia unclear/wrong?

Answer (score -1):

I'd rather say you are a bit nitpicking. You are correct, but I think you would agree that your case is not a combination of anything in the proper sense. (Also, you could broaden your statement and consider "combinations" with ANY states) (promoted from comment to answer)